# java enum access issue by variable

Tags: java, enums

I see a weird situation and wonder if I missed something.  I have one class define an enum like this

```
public class Foo {
  public enum Day { Monday, Tuesday, ...};
  ...
}
```

Then in another class I have

```
public class Bar {
    Foo aFoo=new Foo();

    void test(){
       System.out.println(Foo.Day.Monday);  // ok
       System.out.println(aFoo.Day.Monday);  // complie error Day not accessible
    }
}
```

Anyone have an explanation for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Please refer to the following java docs http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that [when you have an expression like `Q.Id` and `Q` is an expression of type `T`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.2-230) (Q is your `aFoo` and `T = Foo`):

> If there is not exactly one accessible (§6.6) member of the type T ***that is a field named Id***, then a compile-time error occurs.

In other words you can reference a static field with an instance (`aFoo.someStaticVariable`) but not a nested class.

So you need to use `Outerclass.Nestedclass` to access it.

Comment: Thanks.  It explains why, but I don't understand your "By the way" part.

Comment: It is a side note but it is not the reason for the behaviour: in `someInstance.f`, `f` must be a field, whether static or not - `f` can't be a class name. I have edited for clarity.

Comment: Your `enum` is `static` by default (see link in answer), that means it's the same for all instances of `Foo`. So it's not really useful to access it via the instance but it is useful to access it via the class itself. That's the basic idea.

Answer (score 3):

From the [JLS §8.9](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9):

> Nested enum types are implicitly `static`. It is permissible to explicitly declare a nested enum type to be `static`.

Hence it makes no sense to access `Day` through a `Foo` instance; it can only be accessed through the `Foo` class itself as in your first print statement.

Comment: all other statics can be accessed by instances.  why not enum?

Comment: Accessing static fields through class instances is evil. Maybe Java designers realized that and didn't want to add more sulphur to the open wound. :)

Comment: @user3097579 Not static nested classes, which a nested enum is.